# How to make matplotlib.pyplot.fill saved gif looping

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate a fill_between 4 differents points inside matplotlib and I don't know how to update the data. Here is an exemple of my code:

```
data = {'X':[-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -2000, -2000, 0, 0, -3000, -3000, -1000, -1000],
    'Y':[-1000, 1000, 1000, -1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -1000], 
    'Time':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
pts = df[df.Time == 1].iloc[:, :2].values
plt.scatter(df[df.Time == 1].X, df[df.Time == 1].Y)
hull = ConvexHull(pts)
plt.fill(pts[hull.vertices,0], pts[hull.vertices,1],'red',alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(-3500,3500)
plt.ylim(-3000,3000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will show the animation with interval 1000ms.

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
data = {'X':[-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -2000, -2000, 0, 0, -3000, -3000, -1000, -1000],
    'Y':[-1000, 1000, 1000, -1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, -1000], 
    'Time':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = plt.figure()


def animate(i):
    plt.clf()
    plt.xlim(-3500,3500)
    plt.ylim(-3000,3000)

    pts = df[df.Time == i].iloc[:, :2].values
    plt.scatter(df[df.Time == i].X, df[df.Time == i].Y)
    hull = ConvexHull(pts)
    plt.fill(pts[hull.vertices,0], pts[hull.vertices,1],'red',alpha=0.5)
    return

myAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(1,4,1), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

And if you use imagemagick, you can save gif like this.

```
# save animation at 30 frames per second 
myAnimation.save('myAnimation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

(actually this code is mostly from [here](https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/23562/save-animation-to-gif))